# My Apache log file has nothing but "combinedio" on each line

Tags: apache2, logging

I tried to view my Apache2 log with the following command:

```
sudo tail -100 /usr/local/apache2/logs/thewebsitename.log
```

and all it returned were 100 lines saying "combinedio" on each line. How can I view the log?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Apache configuration is faulty.  You will need to fix your Apache configuration so that it starts logging correctly.

"combinedio" is a logging format powered by [mod_logio](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_logio.html).  See on ServerFault: [What is the difference between combined and combinedio Log Formats in Apache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/751429/what-is-the-difference-between-combined-and-combinedio-log-formats-in-apache)   Your Apache config has a line like:

```
CustomLog combinedio
```

There is some problem that is causing Apache not to know that is a nickname of a log format and simply log "combinedio" as a literal for every hit.   The problem may be one of:

- `mod_logio` is not installed or enabled
- the `combinedio` log format is not defined in your configuration

You can either figure out how to fix that module, define that log format, or you can switch to a different log format.

On Ubuntu servers you would enable `mod_logio` using:

```
sudo a2enmod mod_logio
```

You could define the log format by adding a line before your custom log directive:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
```

Or you could change your `CustomLog` statement to a log format that may already exist like:

```
CustomLog combined
```

When you change your Apache configuration, you need to restart your server or reload the configuration using a command like:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

If you are on a managed server or shared hosting, your hosting provider will have to make these changes for you.